# How to get knownTimeZoneNames according to currentLocale

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimezone, nslocale

I want to create a list of `knownTimeZoneNames` automatically translated in the language of the user.
I have this code for countries which works very well, but I can't succeed in do it for `knowntimeZoneNames`.

```
NSLocale *localeTwo = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSArray *countryArray = [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes];
NSMutableArray *sortedCountryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *countryCode in countryArray) {        
    NSString *displayNameString = [localeTwo displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCode];
    [sortedCountryArray addObject:displayNameString];      
    NSLog(@"NSDisplayNameString : %@", displayNameString);
}        
[sortedCountryArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];   
[sortedCountryArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
```

Comment: I hope my answer can help you

Answer (score 0):

`[NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]` makes the thing. Try:

```
NSArray * knownTimeZoneArray = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames];    
NSLog(@"knownTimeZoneArray = %@", knownTimeZoneArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't know how to manage :-(. I am wondering a this time. Do I use "displayNameForKey" or "localizedName" to succeed in the translation of the knowTimeZoneArray ?

Comment: For the moment I still have "Warsaw" instead of "Varsovie" in the french Language. Have you got an idea Gabriel to translate this automatically ?

Comment: MAybe changing the phone (iOS Simulator) Language?

Comment: No it doesn't change, I would like to be so easy ! the list keep the english language.

Comment: I think knownTimeZoneNames retrieves the ISO names for the zones and there is no automatic translations for them.

Comment: It is really surprising because on the above example it's ISOCountry and I succeed in making a translation.??!